How to run a function from a script in another script?
I have two scripts and in one I want, under a certain condition, to give a command to start an action in another script.
public class joystickMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text LivesUI;
    int Lives = 3;

    public void Init()
    {
        Lives = 3;
        LivesUI.text = Lives.ToString();
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "EnemyTag")
        {
            PlayBoom();
            Lives = Lives - 1;
            LivesUI.text = Lives.ToString();

            if (Lives < 1)
            {
                DeadScreen.SetActive(true);
                RestartButton.SetActive(true);
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}

How do I now run the Lives = Lives - 1; action in another script under a certain conditions?

There are no "scripts" in c#. If you want to call a method of a different class, you need an instance of that class, given the method is not static.

Just Lives = Lives - 1, or also the PlayBoom(); and the LivesUI.text = Lives.ToString(); ??

I suspect this is about Unity, or? It would be useful to add the suitable tag to your question.

You could access Lives from another class if you declare it public (it's a private member currently, default accessibility)

First of all as mentioned Lives is currently implicitely private so not visible to any other type.
However, for starters to be honest a class called joystickMove which then .. well, doesn't have anything to do with neither joystick input nor moving an object is completely nonsense!
Ensure you properly separate your types and purposes. Here you have at least two things involved:

Something holding live points
Something reacting to collisions
(And the third thing you didn't show yet but also should influence live points)

(I personally would even split this further into a proper MVVC structure but to keep it simple let's not do this now)
I would split this into e.g.
public class LivesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text LivesUI;

    private int _lives;

    public int Lives
    {
        get => _lives;
        set
        {
            _lives = value;

            UpdateDisplay();
            CheckGameOver();
        }
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        Lives = 3;
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        LivesUI.text = _lives.ToString();
    }

    private void CheckGameOver()
    {
        if (Lives <= 0)
        {
            DeadScreen.SetActive(true);
            RestartButton.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

And then another component for the collisions
public class CollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
     [Header("Settings")]
     [SerializeField] private string collideWithTag = "EnemyTag";

     [Header("External Dependencies")]
     [SerializeField] private LivesController livesController;

     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         if (collision.CompareTag(collideWithTag))
         {
             PlayBoom();
             livesController.Lives -= 1;
         }
     }

     private void PlayBoom()
     {
         ...
     }
}


And just for completeness - as mentioned now you still have a fix dependency directly coupling the ColisionController to the LivesController. Instead I would have a third instance - the Model (M) and rather let them both go through this one. Depending on how deep you want to get into Dependency Injection etc in theory this one wouldn't even have to be a MonoBehaviour at all - but for simplicity for now:
public class DataModel : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int _lives;

    public int Lives
    {
        get => _lives;
        set
        {
            _lives = value;
            LivesChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action<int> LivesChanged;
}

and then
public class CollisionController : MonoBehaviour
{
     private DataModel dataModel;

     public void Init(DataModel dataModel)
     {
         this.dataModel = dataModel;
     }

     void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
     {
         ...

         dataModel.Lives -= 1;
     }
}

and
public class LivesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Text LivesUI;

    public void Init(DataModel dataModel)
    {
        dataModel.LivesChanged += OnLivesChanged;
        OnLivesChanged(dataModel.Lives);

        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void OnLivesChanged(int lives)
    {
        LivesUI.text = lives.ToString();
    
        if (Lives <= 0)
        {
            DeadScreen.SetActive(true);
            RestartButton.SetActive(true);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}


Спасибо, я попробую ваш метод. Это всего лишь фрагмент моего кода. Там есть часть отвечающий за движение игрока, поэтому он так и называется.

If you mean OOP check these codes.
You have to create an object of that class (like a variable) to access all public members. Every object has it's own group members.
Main class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace oopProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// other_class is not declared as static class. so you have to create an object to access all public members in it.
        /// other_class must be public and non static.
        /// </summary>

        void operations_on_other_class()
        {
            other_class oc = new other_class(); // Create an object of that class or you say it script.
            MessageBox.Show(oc.lives.ToString()); // outputs: 80
            MessageBox.Show(oc.some_function(2, 6).ToString()); // outputs: 2x6=12
        }
    }
}

other_class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace oopProject
{
    public class other_class    // defined as public
    {
        public int lives = 80; // defined as public
        public int some_function(int a, int b) // defined as public
        {
            return a * b;
        }
    }
}

